# Get current theme when App starts - Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, themes

I want to see what is the current theme in Windows Phone 7 so that I can change our text, image and color based on the current theme.

For example, if the current theme is yellow, I will change all the color of image to yellow.

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/windowsphone/detecting_the_theme.htm

Comment: Take a look at the Theme class available here: https://github.com/ZombieHunter/WP7-Theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the current theme resource using the following code:

```
Application.Current.Resources["<ThemeResourceName>"]
```

Available theme resource names are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). The result of the above operation will have to be cast to the appropriate type; for example, if you're fetching the `PhoneAccentBrush` you must cast the result to a `SolidColorBrush`.

Answer (score 3):

Writing theme aware Silverlight apps for Windows Phone 7 is covered pretty well at a high level in this article: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2010/09/14/being-theme-aware-in-windows-phone-7-silverlight-apps.aspx